# How to SELECT urls that have not been accessed in 1 month?

Tags: mysql

I have a two column table.  One column contains urls of type VARCHAR and the other column contains dates of the type DATE.

How do I select the urls that have not been accessed in 1 month?

For example if this is my data

```
url         date
google.com  2/2/2013
yahoo.com   2/2/2013
google.com  3/2/2013
```

The select statement should return `yahoo.com` since that url has not been accessed in over 1 month

Comment: can you give sample records with desired resu;t?

Comment: How do you join data from those tables?

Comment: It's one table - yes I can give an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT a1.url 
FROM accesses AS a1
WHERE a1.url NOT IN (
  SELECT a2.url 
  FROM accesses AS a2
  WHERE a2.access >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
);
```

Which is the reverse of Danny Beckett's answer.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db7aa/4

Comment: Thanks! just add a  `GROUP BY a2.url` at the end of the nested query and it should be perfect

Comment: It's not the reverse, it's a different query altogether. I took it at face value that the OP wanted to return all rows with a `date` older than 1 month. In fact, he/she wanted (and I don't know how you figured this out, since it isn't stated anywhere in the question) to have URLs that show up multiple times, and where one of the multiple is *newer* than 1 month, to *not* show in the result set. As I say, just 2 completely different queries - not the "reverse".